# Looping through nested key:value pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-3.x, nested-loops

I am new to python, your help will be greatly appreciated.

1) I have a data structure

```
Table = {'1': {'From': 'A', 'To': 'B'}, '2': {'From': 'C', 'To': 'D'}}
```

2) I want to loop through `Table` and print values associated with 'From'.

3) I expect output to be -> `A C`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for v in Table.values():
    print v["From"]
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> table = {'1': {'From': 'A', 'To': 'B'}, '2': {'From': 'C', 'To': 'D'}}
>>> print ' '.join(row['From'] for row in table.values())
A C
```

So what am I doing here?

- the `(row['From'] for row in table.values())` thing is a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It creates a generator (similar to an iterator in other languages).
- We send this generator into join(), which is a function in the `str` class: it accepts any iterable thing (list, tuple, generator...) and creates a string containing all of the elements...
- ...separated by the string we called it on (a single space in this case, but it could be any string).

Of course, @YOBA's solution is much easier to read, but I just couldn't resist confusing you for a moment -- and hopefully teaching you some concepts that may be of use in other situations. Good luck, have fun! :)